Summarise by multiple columns dax
I need to group the amounts in the table. There could be projects with different level 2 and 3 deliverers. I have tried this dax, but get: The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression. Can you help?
Summarise = 
        var tab1=
        SUMMARIZE('Table',
        'Table'[Proj Ref],
        'Table'[Deliverer],
        'Table'[Level 2 Deliverer],
        'Table'[Level 3 Deliverer],
        'Table'[Period],
        "Totals",sum('Table'[Amount])
        )
        var a=sumx(tab1,[Totals])
RETURN a


Your expression is returning a scalar value (ie a number) where it is expecting a table. I'm assuming you have the above as a Calculated Table. What are you needing? A Table or a Value?

You're using  SUMMARIZE  and then you are trying to use SUMX over a single variable that's your issue, just remove the variable.
SummarisedAmount = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Proj Ref],
        'Table'[Deliverer],
        'Table'[Level 2 Deliverer],
        'Table'[Level 3 Deliverer],
        'Table'[Period],
        "Totals", SUM('Table'[Amount])
    )


Thank you, but I still get this: The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression.

I pasted the wrong code, simply use the SUMMARIZE without any variable.
